# Jquery autocompelete - key press

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

We want to implement autocompelete using Jquery.

We need to enable the user to add text and to save the new text.
something like  on key press event.
In Addition I want enable to user to add text into the input text.

```
$('#id').autocomplete({
    source: url,
    select:  function (event, ui) {
        // code..
    }
});
```

We have tried to do this using change event , but this is not good enough since according to the API the change event is fire only after onBlur is fire (when the user live the input text).

Can someone help how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

John & Yuri.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').autocomplete({
source:function(request, response) 
       {
            var text = $("#idofthetext").val()
            alert(text);
       }
select:  function (event, ui) {
    // code..
}
});
```

do you want to do something like this? var text will give you the text when user type in the input field with id "idofthetext".